# How to show delete icon near to fullcalender event

Tags: fullcalendar

How to show a delete icon near to fullcalender event .. I tried to add html img tag but it is shown as text in event...it is not showing the image icon....

Comment: I have resolve the issue.....eventRender: function(event, element) {                                          
 element.find('span.fc-event-title').html(element.find('span.fc-event-title').text());       
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue.....

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { element.find('span.fc-event-title').html(element.find('span.fc-event-title').te‌​xt()); },
```

Comment: It should go in your FullCalendar init. Something like 
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: ...,
  eventRender: function(...
});`

Comment: When Add that the calendar disappears.